# Xcode Firebase query to fetch spacific data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data model

```
{

"channels":{
    "channel_key_0":{
        "creator":"pqr",
        "name":"Channel-1",
        "participant":{
            "id_1":"Jack",
            "id_2":"Harry"
        }
    },
    "channel_key_1":{
        "creator":"xyz",
        "name":"Channel-2",
        "participant":{
            "id_3":"Jerry",
            "id_2":"Harry"
        }
    }
}
```

}

From given above structure I want to fetch channels of only where participant has value `"id_1": "Jack"`.

I am new to Firebase database. Need help to write this query. I tried few things `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("channels").queryOrdered(byChild: "participant").queryEqual(toValue: "Jack", childKey: "id_1")`, but giving me null data.

Improvement in structure is also welcome. My idea is to build personal chat by applying this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this way.

```
let ref =  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("channels")
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "participant/id_1").queryEqual(toValue: "Jack")
   .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    print(snapshot)
})
```

Comment: Perfecto... Thanks buddy.

Comment: Quick question.... Do you have any idea how to use regex in place of `participant/id_1` like `participant/any_thing` ?

Comment: @JayPandya I haven't try something like that. :(, Will respond here if I find suitable example